# Why I get error: are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I added C# code  in `aspx` file, but it is showing error.

This code I add to asp file:

```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute]
   public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
   {
        string[] names = {"Ram","Ankit","Sam","Sahil","Rajan","Rahul","Sajan"};
        var namesList = from tmp in names where tmp.ToLower().StartWith(prefixText) select tmp;

    return names;
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'StartWith' and no extension method 'StartWith' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here is n declared in  my page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
```

Any idea how can I fix the error?

Comment: Start**s**With ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the s in `StartsWith` - `StartWith`.